# Cannot write to Apache www directory LAMP

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, permissions, fedora

I've got Fedora 16 running Apache, PHP & MySQL. 
I want to do 2 things:

1. Share a directory within the www directory over Samba
2. Use CMS systems that have automatic install/configure scripts

I've successfully gotten apache running & serving up webpages while still sharing the www directory over samba on a previous machine running the exact same version of Fedora, but this machine seems to be very stubborn. I had an issue sharing a different directory over Samba and figured out it was an SElinux issue. I had to change the SElinux label to "samba_share_t" in order to get that share to work. But the SElinux context for the www directory and subsequent directories is "read all http scripts and the daemon" so I'm pretty sure if I change that to the Samba Share, http will no longer work properly.

So without the samba share working (and without FTP running) I'm having to place the files on the server through the physical box itself. As my local user I created a directory in www and placed files for a CMS system in there using fedora's file manager no problems. However when I go to run the install script for the CMS in the browser, I get errors saying "cannot create file, check permissions". The first was a CMS I had never used before so I figured it might be an issue with the CMS, however I tried installing another CMS and I get a similar error.

With both tries I manually set the permissions for the www directory and all files enclosed all the way up 777, and set the owner to my own user (instead of root). Everything else required by the CMS (Apache, MySQL, PHP) is running fine and combined with the error I get when trying to access my /var/www samba share "You do not have permission to access \SERVER\share" I'm going with it's a permissions issue. What I don't understand is how I can still have a permissions issue when I've chmod'd the directory recursively all the way to 777?